# How can I copy a result set from a sql job to a remote server within the job through automation?

Tags: sql-server

I have a SQL Server job that runs a query, which outputs locally however need it to copy to a remote server. I am unsure how to automate that part. I have the SQL server job setup, the first step is to run the query and output locally, the second step I need to copy the text file outputted locally to the remote server to a shared drive. I am unsure if this is possible.

Comment: You can use SSIS for that.

Comment: Agreed, either SSIS or Setup a [Linked Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/linked-servers/create-linked-servers-sql-server-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15)...